# False Color Composite with MODIS data in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis, composite, arcmap

I'm trying to make a false color composite from a .hdf MODIS file in ArcMap.  I know how to do it with Landsat data and I've seen tutorials for working with MODIS in other programs, but I can't figure out how to make a false color composite with MODIS data in ArcMap. I think I'm just missing something very basic, but if someone could walk me through it, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the imagery in ArcMap, then under "Layer Properties", select "Symbology -> RGB Composite" and choose the bands you want to display as R/G/B.

If you do not have a multi-band image, you should stack the layers using the ArcToolbox.